# Obama said "gin up about the prospect of rallying behind whoever emerges from this process". Did he misspeak?

Tags: phrases, phrase-usage, speech

> “Everybody needs to chill out about the candidates but **gin up about the prospect** of rallying behind whoever emerges from this process,” Obama said in response to a question about the primary, according to CNN. ([source](https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/2019/11/22/obama-tells-democrats-worried-about-primary-field-chill-out/))

Obama's use of the phrase "gin up about" grates. People say "gin up something" to mean *to stir up something*, *to generate or create something, controversy or sentiment*. I have also heard "we need to gin up the economy" used mostly in semi-official contexts, meaning "revive, strengthen", which seems somewhat close to Obama's intended meaning.

It appears Obama meant to say people should be prepared for or pumped about whoever emerged as the winner of the Democratic primaries and get ready to support them. But I have never heard "gin up about". A quick Google Books search points to only one modern attestations from [National Journal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Journal). The content is garbled, possibly from OCR problems, but it could also be from Obama. I have also read [this page](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/ginned-up.html) where the origin of the phrase is discussed and "to excite or enliven" is mentioned as a possible meaning, but still nothing about "gin up about".

Obama is a capable and fairly eloquent speaker (very much so compared to *someone*), but did he misuse this phrase?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, he didn’t misspeak. He merely took a colloquial expression normally used transitively and roped it into an intransitive use so that he could have two balanced, parallel expressions that worked the same away on both sides.

*Chill out* is used intransitively, so he needed to also have something similarly intransitive to oppose it with. **And** it needs to be in the same colloquial register to maintain the parallelism. So what’s he supposed to do here?

It’s easy to find colloquial synonyms for *chill out* in the sense of *relax*, like *calm down, simmer down, loosen up, hang loose*, and so on and so forth. So what’s the opposite of *relaxing* or *getting/becoming relaxed*? Certainly one obvious answer is *becoming excited*, but that one is no good as foil to *chill out*.

So he used *gin up*, which is a perfectly fine colloquialism from the same register as that of *chill out*. But here’s the thing: normally *gin up, gin out, gin together* are used transitively with a separable object. But he needed it to be intransitive so that *gin up about the prospects* could balance against *chill out about the candidates*.

What else was he supposed to use? He couldn’t have used *awaken about* because it’s got the wrong register. Sure, maybe he could have used *get fired up about*, but that needs an extra word compared with *chill out about* or *gin up about*. I guess *fire up* or *rev up* might have been possible, but they’re not quite so colloquial as *chilling out* and *ginning up* are.

In sum, he deliberately chose a balanced pair of matching colloquial expressions. What’s bothering you is that to do this, he had to use the second one **intransitively** so it could match the first one’s intransitivity, but he chose one that is rarely used intransitively. That’s why it grates upon your ear.

However, he’s a native speaker so he gets to do that sort of thing if it pleases him to do so. Moreover, he’s one who is renowned for his deliberate and measured tone coupled with his folksy delivery. So it isn’t a case of him misspeaking. Rather, he’s exercising his inherent native-speaker licence to freely invent novel approaches in how he uses his own language whenever it serves him to do so. Which here it clearly did.

Comment: Interesting, _chill out_ came here so long ago that I suspect that many British people think that it's a British English phrase. We also have _calm down, simmer down, loosen up, hang loose, get fired uo_ and _rev up_ which are either as much British as American or were adopted at least as long ago as 'chill out'. However 'gin up' is completely new to me and is, I suspect, unfamiliar to most British English speakers. To me _gin_ has two meanings: the alcoholic drink and the Romany meaning of _know_. When I saw the expression I thought it was a misspelling of _gen up_ meaning _learn_.

Comment: I do wonder whether _gin up_ is related to _cotton gin_ which, I understand, came from _engine_ and is, as far as I know a uniquely American term.

Comment: [Grammarist](https://grammarist.com/idiom/gin-something-up/) says it may be related to the practice of introducing hot or spicy substances (e.g. ginger) into the "delicate parts" of horses to make them seem more lively.

Comment: The OED agrees: **4. transitive. U.S. colloquial. With up. To stir up or intensify (a situation, process, etc.); to arouse or intensify strong feelings in (a person or group). Cf. ginger v. 3.  [Perhaps influenced both semantically and etymologically by to ginger up (see ginger v. 3)] .** *1996   Weekly Standard (Nexis) 1 Jan. 27   Lugar is known for his decorousness but for a moment he looked as if he were ginning himself up to give a big hug.*

Comment: Mr. Obama was merely using phrases he was familiar with, transitively or otherwise.

The origin of "gin" does come from the deep South and the cotton gin. This was the cotton *Engine*, invented by Eli Whitney. The less sophisticated people who were delighted to buy and use it were unused to words beginning with vowels. As such "engine" became "gin". Other examples can be found.